# Which preposition is correct "in" or "to"?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

Could you tell me what preposition "**in**" or "**to**" should I use in the sentence below?

- I am passionate about making a positive difference **in**/**to** the lives of the
  children I visit.

Comment: They're both fine, and I can't see any scope for thinking they might have different *meanings*. For your *exact* (somewhat cliched) context, [*"**in**" is far more common*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=positive+difference+in+the+lives%2Cpositive+difference+to+the+lives&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpositive%20difference%20in%20the%20lives%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpositive%20difference%20to%20the%20lives%3B%2Cc0), but it's no more "correct" than ***to***.

Comment: To me, here, *in* means "inside", while *to* "toward" or "in the direction of".

Answer (score 1):

I think of it this way

> Having a boyfriend/girlfriend is a difference **in** one's life.
>   Winning the lottery is a difference **to** one's life.
>
> A change **in** one's life can make a difference **to** one's life.

Comment: for sake of argument, I'd say it's the other way around. I have no arguments, do you?

Comment: The way I think of it: since boyfriend/girlfriend becomes a part of one's life, I think of it as *in* my life, winning the lottery is an external force, though it does effect one's life it is not "in" my life but is an effect *to* one's life. For example, the weather will make a change *to* my life (external influence), but not *in* my life (an incorporated part of).

Comment: Yes, you said that, but your argument is based on the conclusion, not the other way around, "*though it does effect one's life it is not* "in" *my life*". I posit, a friend is no more or less external or internal to your life than the weather. Your argument is fuzzy, where do you draw the line?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to delineate that you want to make changes to those children, use "to", which indicates toward a subject.

Answer (score 0):

If I am going to choose between in or to I would choose in. Also, I think into the lives of children I visit would work.